# Submit an universal app as iPad only app to Apple

Tags: xcode, ipad, submission, universal-binary

I created an universal app with the window template in xcode. Now I want submit just the iPad version of my app, because the iPhone version is not yet fully programmed.

How is this possible? What do I have to change? (target settings, info.plist, etc.?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two things.   First is remember you have settings for active target, and project.  I'm not sure which place things *should* be, but I made these on the target.

Set 'Build Active Target Only' to true.
Set 'Target Family Device' to iPad.

You'll know this worked because the number of compilations will be cut in half, and when you upload to iTunes Connect it won't require an iPhone screen shot.

Comment: I don't even see a "Build Active Target Only" option in 4.6 or 5.0. Perhaps it no longer exists. (There's "Build Active Architecture Only", but that's unrelated.)

Comment: Yeah, this option is no longer available now.

Answer (score 4):

When you submit to Apple, you can choose to limit it to certain platforms during the upload process.

Comment: This has changed recently.  Instead of limiting the platform during upload you now define required features in your info.plist.  These are combined to determine which devices your app supports.  You can't set it manually in iTunes Connect any longer.