# How can I revert my Universal app back to iPhone only?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

In a silly mistake, I ran the "Upgrade current Target for iPad" assistant in Xcode. I'd like to target the iPad some time with my app, but right now, I don't have the time and just want to ship it. Is there an easy way to remove the iPad specific changes from my app?

Specifically, what I'm after is, I want to be able to run the app in the little "iPhone" window on the iPad (the one that lets you blow up the size of the app by pixel doubling). Right now, my view just hangs in there somewhere and looks weird.

Any help?

Comment: Pull the latest version from your repository?  You do have it in source control, don't you?

Comment: I do, but exactly this commit is one of those where, instead of cleanly committing each change, I just did a whole bunch of stuff at once, and at this point, it seems easier to do it by hand than to look through all the changes. It's really stupid, I know, and I kinda learned my lesson about this.

Comment: Hahaha, that makes sense.  I have to admit that I'm guilty of that quite often too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found help in this question: [Submit an universal app as iPad only app to Apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706215/submit-an-universal-app-as-ipad-only-app-to-apple)

The solution is

- Open the Target configuration: Project -> Edit Active Target
- In build settings, set

  - Architectures: Standard (armv6(
  - Build active architecture only: YES
  - Targeted Device Family: iPhone

Comment: This worked for me but in my info plist I also had to change the NSMainNibFile~ipad (Main nib file base name (iPad)) to match the non-iPad version.

Comment: There's misinformation here, I think. CPU architectures have a many-to-many relationship with device families. You shouldn't be touching your architecture settings at all when swapping between building for iPhone/iPad/both. All you need to change is the targeted device family.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it offhand, but you could create another project (then make a copy) and then run the same "upgrade current target for iPad" and look for differences.

Comment: I'm tempted to accept this answer, but I tried it and it didn't really help me. Lots of diffs in the Xcodeproj-file and one diff in the plist. The Plist one doesn't make any difference, and the Xcodeproj seems to indicate it's one of the build settings, but I can't find which.

Answer (score 0):

Does Upgrade for iPad create a new snapshot. I thought mine created one before I did it automatically, but I'm not positive. If so, just revert back to the snapshot